# testing ember.js connectOutlet

Tags: testing, ember.js

Does anyone have any good advice for testing that the ember route's connectOutlets has been successful?

For example, I have the following routes:

```
vault: Ember.Route.extend
  route: '/vault'
  connectOutlets: (router, event) ->
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet 'exercises'
  index: Ember.Route.extend
    route: '/'
    connectOutlets: (router, event) ->
      exercises = WZ.store.find(WZ.Exercise)
      router.get('exercisesController').connectOutlet 'main', 'exercisesHome', exercises
```

How would I go about checking that this was having the desired behaviour?

I can test the currentState.path like this:

```
it 'should transition to vault', ->
  Ember.run =>
    @router.transitionTo 'vault'
  expect(@router.getPath('currentState.path')).toEqual 'root.vault'
```

But I don't think this is a very good test.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this code does not deserve testing.

First, let's formally define a desired behavior for this code:

When the router transitions to 'vault/index' state, and everything is OK, the following happens:

1. Ember creates new instance of ExercisesHomeView
2. Ember sets the content property of exercisesHomeController to a list of exercises
3. Ember connects the created view to the main outlet in the ExercisesView template

You see, all the meaningful work is done by Ember. Therefore, strictly speaking, there is nothing to test, since we do not test third-party code.

In my opinion, this code has only one thing that *maybe* deserves testing: whether we are providing the right data to the controller. Even then, I'd test this code only after I was faced with its misbehavior.